# Aligning JQuery UI icon in the button

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm having a little difficulty getting the icon image to align properly in my button. If you go to http://jsfiddle.net/Vw9Z6/7/ , you will notice the icon floats higher than the word "Continue". I want the icon and the word "Continue" to be on the same line. I can futz around with `margin-top` to get it working, but in my opinion, it may not be reliable depending on the user screen resolution.

Any idea on how I might go about solving this?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `.my-button-icon` with the following:

```
.my-button-icon {
    margin-left:10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The `float: right;` was messing the alignment up: http://jsfiddle.net/Vw9Z6/11/

**Update:**

You may want to play around with `vertical-align: middle;` as well. I think at the current text size the alignment looks better without the `vertical-align` style, but this could change with increasing/decreasing font.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the button's position to relative and then absolute position the icon within the button? If you do that, it shouldn't matter what resolution is being viewed on.